# How to copy from 1 column to another in an Amazon S3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My current structure is like this:

```
[
   {id: 1, firstName: 'Ao ', secondName: 'Ou' },
   {id: 2, firstName: 'Bo ', secondName: 'Ou' }
]
```

I want to change the data to something like this:

```
 [
     {id: 1, firstName: 'Ao ', secondName: 'Ou', fullName: 'Ao Ou' },
     {id: 2, firstName: 'Bo ', secondName: 'Ou', fullName: 'Bo Ou' }
 ]
```

I am new to AWS so I don't know how to do it. Is there anyway to do it via commands rather than manually adding all the data?

Comment: FYI that neither of those is valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You can not edit the file in s3 directly .
You can load it edit and reupload to S3 again .